# Elementwise and in python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two `python lists` `A` and `B` of equal length each containing only boolean values. Is it possible to get a third list `C` where `C[i] = A[i] and B[i]` for `0 <= i < len(A)` without using loop?

I tried following

`C = A and B`

but probably it gives the list `B`

I also tried

`C = A or B`

which gives first list

I know it can easily be done using for loop in single line like `C = [x and y for x, y in zip(A, B)]`.

Comment: If you don't want loops, you may want to have a look at numpy.

Comment: @ayhan Which also uses loops, just hides them in C code..

Comment: @ShamshadAlam  You will have to have a loop, either an implicit or an explicit one. Why does it matter?

Comment: Yes, but it is numpy that uses those loops, not the OP.

Comment: @DeepSpace It doesn't matter to me. I just wanted to check whether it is possible without loop or not.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you use numpy to use these kind of predicates over arrays. Now, I don't think you can avoid loops to achieve what you want, but... if you don't consider mapping or enumerating as a form of looping, you could do something like this (C1):

```
A = [True, True, True, True]
B = [False, False, True, True]

C = [x and y for x, y in zip(A, B)]
C1 = map(lambda (i,x): B[i] and x, enumerate(A))
C2 = [B[i] and x for i,x in enumerate(A)]

print C==C1==C2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without an explicit loop by using `map`, which performs the loop internally, at C speed. Of course, the actual `and` operation is still happening at Python speed, so I don't think it'll save much time (compared to doing essentially the same thing with Numpy, which can not only do the looping at C speed, it can do the *and* operation at C speed too. Of course, there's also the overhead of converting between native Python lists & Numpy arrays).

Demo:

```
from operator import and_

a = [0, 1, 0, 1]
b = [0, 0, 1, 1]
c = map(and_, a, b)
print c
```

**output**

```
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Note that the `and_` function performs a bitwise *and* operation, but that should be ok since you're operating on boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you can't.

Except in the trivial way, which is by calling a function that does this for you, using a loop. If you want this kind of nice syntax you can use libraries as suggested: map, numpy, etc. Or you can write your own function.

If what you are looking for is syntactic convenience, Python does not allow overloading operators for built-in types such as list.

Oh, and you can use recursion, if that's "not a loop" for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get a third list `C` where `C[i] = A[i] and B[i]` for `0 <= i < len(A)` without using loop?

Kind of:

```
class AndList(list):
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.A[index] and self.B[index]

A = [False, False, True, True]
B = [False, True, False, True]
C = AndList(A, B)

print isinstance(C, list) and all(C[i] == (A[i] and B[i])
                                  for i in range(len(A)))
```

Prints `True`.